# Converting date into unix timestamp not giving expected result

Tags: datetime, entities

Basically I was trying to get age from date of birth, for which I am using `Computed Field` module.

Following code was used:

```
$isoArray = explode ( '-', substr($entity->field_dob1[0]['value'],0,10));
$bdayunix = mktime ( 00, 00, 00, (int)$isoArray[1], (int)$isoArray[2], (int)$isoArray[0]);

$nowunix = time();
$unixage = $nowunix - $bdayunix;
$age = floor($unixage/ (365 * 24 * 60 * 60));

$entity_field[0]['value'] = $age;
```

When I checked the code, I found that this part of code is not giving the correct  result:

```
 $isoArray = explode ( '-', substr($entity->field_dob1[0]['value'],0,10));
 $bdayunix = mktime ( 00, 00, 00, (int)$isoArray[1], (int)$isoArray[2], (int)$isoArray[0]);
```

I can say that because when I try to convert **$bdayunix** into date,whatever the date of  birth is, I always get the result 1999.

```
ie; $dob = date("Y",$bdayunix ); always gives result:1999.
```

Could you please tell me where I am going wrong? Is this problem of Computed field module or I am doing some mistake in my code ?

(Date format in users bday field is yyyy-mm-dd and I have tried all types: Date, DateISO format and Date Unix timestamp).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution .

If we select Field type as Date(Unix Timestamp) then `$entity->field_dob1[0]['value']` will return unix timestamp value which can be directly used.

So if anyone in same requirement can use the following code:

```
$bdayunix = $entity->field_date_of_birth['und'][0]['value'];
$nowunix = time();
$unixage = $nowunix - $bdayunix;
$age = floor($unixage/ (365 * 24 * 60 * 60));

$entity_field[0]['value'] = $age;
```

PS: Dont forget to select field type as Date(Unix Timestamp).